# Javascript detect audio devices

Tags: javascript, audio

Is there a possibility to detect PC's audio devices from javascript and separate sounds between them? For example sound1 will play through speakers, and sound2 will play through headphones?

Comment: I don't believe JS has access to such low-level mechanisms, but who knows. I may be wrong

Comment: If you mean client-side JavaScript that's executed in the browser, then I sure as hell hope not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this via javascript from inside of the browser.

Javascript, in a browser, is run within a sandbox and does not have direct access to client system.